# Is my flash game local or on the internet?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I'm currently developing a flash game and I need to be able to test it on my local machine and also on the web.

When running locally I use some dummy test data and when online it is joined to an API.

While in development I would like to be able to detect where I'm running so I can switch between these automatically. Is there a way to detect this in Flash?

Comment: Set a development variable to true? I don't understand the question. It seems too simplisti, what actual problem are you having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check on your base movie clip (the root movie) the **loaderInfo.url** property,

when you're running locally **loaderInfo.url** will start with *file://*

Use substr() to extract the beginning and check against that value.

That's how I do it for my flash apps.